# Удаление файла БД SQLIte? (файл используется)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlite

**Не удается удалить файл БД SQLite после создания.**

Ошибка: "*Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "mydb.sqlite", так как этот файл используется другим процессом*"

*(Возникает также при попытке удалить файл с помощью проводника, после закрытия приложения в проводнике файл удаляется нормально)*

Создание:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=mydb.sqlite; Version=3; Password=myPassword;", true))
{
    db.Open();
    DataTable eritable = new DataTable();
    eritable.Clear();

    var cmd = @"CREATE  TABLE tabel (par TEXT)";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(cmd, db);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    db.Close();
}
```

Удаление:

```
File.Delete("mydb.sqlite");
```

Использую Visual Studio 2013, C# .Net

Comment: File.Delete("mydb.sqlite"); вызываете после конструкции using()?

Comment: Я полагаю, Вы хотели сделать `db.Close()`, а не `db.Clone()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете клон соединения

```
db.Clone();
```

У этого объекта вы нигде не вызываете метод [Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326260(v=vs.71).aspx), чтобы тем самым освободить неуправляемые ресурсы соединения.

Поэтому вы должны добавить явный вызов метода Dispose после того, как клонированный объект вам больше не нужен.

```
var cloneDb = (SQLiteConnection)db.Clone();
cloneDb.Dispose();
```

Тогда предполагаю, ваша проблема исчезнет.

EDIT: Вот пример, кода, когда файл БД удаляется успешно

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=mydb.sqlite; Version=3; ", true))
{
    db.Open();
    DataTable eritable = new DataTable();
    eritable.Clear();

    var cmd = @"CREATE  TABLE tabel (par TEXT)";
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(cmd, db))
    { 
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

File.Delete("mydb.sqlite");
```

Проблема была в том, что класс`SQLiteCommand` тоже является классом, реализующим интерфейс `IDisposable`, но вызова метода этого не было, поэтому он не освобождал ресурсы подключения к БД.

Comment: Соединение пробовал закрывать как `db.Close();` так и `db.Dispose();` при этом  `File.Delete("mydb.sqlite");` вне **using**. **Проблема не исчезает!**

Comment: отредактировал ответ, файл удаляется успешно.

Comment: @trancer1019, автор ответа отредактировал его. Алексей, автор вопроса не получает уведомлений о редактировании ответа. Если пишете автору комментарий, то его нужно упомянуть в нём.

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо за информацию, упустил это момент